# Does our home router also has NAT functionality?

Tags: networking, router, nat

I know about Network Address Translation and how it works by replacing the source IP address (which is private) by its own public IP while forwarding packets into the network.

But the routers that we buy for personal use at home (Wifi routers) to connect to the internet do have a NAT functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they always have NAT functionality. It is for saving IP address and the safe of your devices connecting to Internet.